# In Amazon RDS, how does one enable PLV8 extension?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, postgresql-extensions

I see it is available. Just can't find the right documentation to help me enable it.

[From the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/CHAP_PostgreSQL.html#PostgreSQL.Concepts.General.UpgradingPLv8), I entered the following command and got:

```
postgres=> select * from pg_available_extensions where name in ('plv8','plls','plcoffee');
   name   | default_version | installed_version |                     comment                      
----------+-----------------+-------------------+--------------------------------------------------
 plcoffee | 2.3.8           |                   | PL/CoffeeScript (v8) trusted procedural language
 plls     | 2.3.8           |                   | PL/LiveScript (v8) trusted procedural language
 plv8     | 2.3.8           |                   | PL/JavaScript (v8) trusted procedural language
(3 rows)
```

PLV8 looks to be available.

Comment: Step 7. on the docs link?

Comment: I forgot to add that I tried that, but it errored and hinted I need superuser access, which is not available on RDS.

Comment: You should add details of what you’ve tried including error messages to the question. Although from a quick look at the docs from my mobile, you may just need super user access. So... get that ‍♂️ or ask someone who has it to install the extension for you

Answer (score 1):

Just run the following command:

```
create extension plv8;
```